# php if returning a unespected error

Tags: php

i have a php if that is returning me a error, this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', on line that that contains this code: `$result -= 'tm_year' = 1900;` someone knows how to fix that ?

```
if (!function_exists( 'strptime' )) {
        function strptime($strdate, $format) {
            $plop = array( 's' => 'tm_sec', 'i' => 'tm_min', 'H' => 'tm_hour', 'd' => 'tm_mday', 'm' => 'tm_mon', 'Y' => 'tm_year' );
            $regexp = preg_quote( $format, '/' );
            $regexp = str_replace( array( '%d', '%m', '%Y', '%H', '%i', '%s' ), array( '(\d{2})', '(\d{2})', '(\d{4})', '(\d{2})', '(\d{2})', '(\d{2})' ), $regexp );

            if (preg_match( '/^' . $regexp . '$/', $strdate, $m )) {
                $result = array( 'tm_sec' => 0, 'tm_min' => 0, 'tm_hour' => 0, 'tm_mday' => 0, 'tm_mon' => 0, 'tm_year' => 0, 'tm_wday' => 0, 'tm_yday' => 0, 'unparsed' => '' );
                preg_match_all( '/%(\w)/', $format, $patt );
                foreach ($patt[1] as $k => $v) {
                    if (!isset( $plop[$v] )) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $result[$plop[$v]] = intval( $m[$k + 1] );

                    if ($plop[$v] == 'tm_mon') {
                        $result -= $plop[$v] = 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                $result -= 'tm_year' = 1900;
                return $result;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to be.  `'tm_year'` is a string, and you are assigning 1900 to it?

Comment: What is unespected about it?

Comment: i've been decoded this code that waz in ioncube, and i dont know how to fix this error...

Comment: Seems like the line `$result -= $plop[$v] = 1;` would've through the same syntax error (and earlier in the code, too).

Comment: i think 'tm_year' is a array position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'tm_year' is a string that you are trying to assign a value of 1900 to.  You can't do that, thus the error.  Seems like a case of trying to be too cute with writing shorthand code, as one honestly can't tell what your intent is here.